# Formula to fill column cells with incrementing values (LibreOffice)

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 Calc, column have 62 cells(1-62). The first cell starts with decimal value 2147500032. I need fill the rest cells with decimal values by increasing each subsequent value by 65536.

example:

```
2147500032
2147565568
2147631104
2147696640
....
```

How to do this with formula?

**Edit:** my answer: formula is `=H1+65536`, then just to fill the formula into adjacent cells.

Comment: Do you have any attempts so far?

Comment: don't change the question significantly like that. If you have a different question, ask a another one

Answer (score 0):

Put 65536 in cell A1, then H1 is 2147500032.

In cell H2 put :

```
=H1 + $A$1
```

And drag down.